# Android send email in background with loading dialog

Tags: android

My problem is, that I need to send an E-Mail with an attatchment. The problem doesn't lay here. The problem is, that when I click the button to send the email I want a dialoge box that tells the user, that the Email is sending/loading.

I saw examples with functions that run in the background. I tried that, but I'm a newbie in Java. If you have some examples or solutions for me I would appreciate that.

Comment: use `asyncTask` class and in onPost show your dialog and in onBackgroun send your Email

Comment: Also, since he is a beginner in Java/Android I want to note, t hat you can't make UI changes in the `doInBackground`-method. You have to do it on the `onPostExecute` - So start an AsyncTask, in the doInBackground method do the logic, that should be done in background, and then, when it's finished, the onPostExecute method shows the results to the user ( displays a popup or what so ever )

Comment: Ok, I need change part of the App, and I will use that in the most of the aplication.
Thank you a lot.